# Summing categories of financial records per month in a query

Tags: python, database, django

My program is working properly but I'm unconfortable with code repetition.

```
class Movimentacao(models.Model):
    data = models.DateField() # complete datetime field from 2019->2022
    movimentacao = models.CharField(max_length=200) # text field
    valor_da_operacao = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19, decimal_places=2) # decimal field

# get all objects filtered by `movimentacao` field
proventos = Movimentacao.objects.filter(movimentacao__in=('Dividendo', 'Juros Sobre Capital Próprio', 'Rendimento', 'Reembolso')).order_by('data', 'id')

currentDate = proventos[0].data # get date from the first record
lastRecord = proventos.last().id # get ID from the last record

assets = []
stockSum = 0
fiiSum = 0

for m in proventos:    
    if(m.data.month != currentDate.month or lastRecord == m.id):
        dataFormatada = f'{currentDate.strftime("%y")}-{currentDate.strftime("%b")}'
        
        if(lastRecord == m.id):

            # first if-else block (necessary but I'd like to 'remove')
            if(m.movimentacao == 'Dividendo'):
                stockSum += m.valor_da_operacao
        
            if(m.movimentacao == 'Rendimento'):
                fiiSum += m.valor_da_operacao
        
        assets.append([dataFormatada, 'FIIs', fiiSum])
        assets.append([dataFormatada, 'Stocks', stockSum])
        
        stockSum = 0
        fiiSum = 0
        
        currentDate = m.data
    
    # second if-else block (this one I can't remove)
    if(m.movimentacao == 'Dividendo'):
        stockSum += m.valor_da_operacao 
        
    if(m.movimentacao == 'Rendimento'):
        fiiSum += m.valor_da_operacao
```

As you can see, the code below is being repeteaded:

```
if(m.movimentacao == 'Dividendo'):
    stockSum += m.valor_da_operacao

if(m.movimentacao == 'Rendimento'):
    fiiSum += m.valor_da_operacao
```

The goal of this code is to build the `assets` list formatted accordingly below:

```
[
  ["19-Nov", "FII", 411.97], ["19-Nov", "Stocks", 0], 
  ["19-Dec", "FII", 368.21], ["19-Dec", "Stocks", 1542.08], 
  ["20-Jan", "FII", 0], ["20-Jan", "Stocks", 401.06], 
]
```

In this way, I'd like to see if it's possible to "remove" the first if-else statement, keeping the code working properly (this would be my first choice).

The issue is: if I remove the first if-else statement, the variable `m.movimentacao` from the last object is not added inside `stockSum` or `fiiSum` variables - that was the reason I need to insert the first if-else statement. The last object can't reach the last if-else statement to be checked either `m.movimentacao` is a 'Dividendo' or 'Rendimento'.

If not, what is the best way to avoid code repetition in this case (function use)?

Comment: This appears to increment `stockSum` or `fiiSum` twice when processing a record that whose ID is equal to `lastRecord` - once before writing to `assets` and once after. Is that the correct behaviour?

Comment: Sorry for bad description! I just edited my question and improved text description. I hope it's better now!

Comment: Are you primarily interested in building `assets` as the result? Wouldn't you also want to do another two `assets.append(…)` statements at the end?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mixing Portuguese and English makes this code messy.  Please pick one or the other.  I recommend coding consistently in English, because Python, its library, and its code ecosystem are in English, so Portuguese will always feel out of place.

Why do you call `.filter(movimentacao__in=('Dividendo', 'Juros Sobre Capital Próprio', 'Rendimento', 'Reembolso')`, when only "Dividendo" and "Rendimento" matter for building `assets`?  Also, wouldn't you want to do another two `assets.append(…)` statements at the end of this code?

This date formatting code is clumsy:

> ```
> dataFormatada = f'{currentDate.strftime("%y")}-{currentDate.strftime("%b")}'
> ```

… and it could be better expressed as

```
dataFormatada = currentDate.strftime("%y-%b")
```

But really, none of this loop should exist: **all of the filtering and summation should be done by the database instead**!  Transferring so much data from the database to Python for analysis defeats the purpose of the database.  It would be more efficient, scalable, and readable to do this in SQL rather than Python.

Here's a query (and a [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_15&fiddle=cfae16ec2e13a30a0693b490a93e2336)) for [postgresql](/questions/tagged/postgresql) that gets you the same results:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
        date_trunc('month', data) AS mes,
        CASE
            WHEN movimentacao = 'Dividendo' THEN 'Stocks'
            ELSE 'FIIs'
        END AS categoria,
        SUM(valor_da_operacao) OVER monthly AS total
    FROM Movimentacao
    WHERE movimentacao IN ('Dividendo', 'Rendimento')
    WINDOW monthly AS (PARTITION BY date_trunc('month', data), movimentacao)
    ORDER BY mes, categoria;
```

You can use a similar query for [sqlite](/questions/tagged/sqlite), except that the datetime functions are different:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
        date(data, 'start of month') AS mes,
        CASE
            WHEN movimentacao = 'Dividendo' THEN 'Stocks'
            ELSE 'FIIs'
        END AS categoria,
        SUM(valor_da_operacao) OVER monthly AS total
    FROM Movimentacao
    WHERE movimentacao IN ('Dividendo', 'Rendimento')
    WINDOW monthly AS (PARTITION BY date(data, 'start of month'), movimentacao)
    ORDER BY mes, categoria;
```

Well, *almost* the same results.  With your Python code, if there is any month in which there is a `Dividendo` but no `Rendimento`, or *vice versa*, both "FIIs" and "Stocks" get appended to `assets` anyway — one of them having a 0 value.  With some creativity and perhaps some Common Table Expressions, the SQL query can be tweaked to produce such 0 values as well:

```sql
WITH MovimentacaoRelevante AS (
    SELECT date(data, 'start of month') AS mes,
           movimentacao,
           valor_da_operacao
        FROM Movimentacao
        WHERE movimentacao IN ('Dividendo', 'Rendimento')
), MovimentacaoRelevanteComZeros AS (
    SELECT * FROM MovimentacaoRelevante
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT mes, 'Dividendo', 0 AS total FROM MovimentacaoRelevante
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DISTINCT mes, 'Rendimento', 0 AS total FROM MovimentacaoRelevante
) SELECT DISTINCT                                    
        mes,
        CASE
            WHEN movimentacao = 'Dividendo' THEN 'Stocks'
            ELSE 'FIIs'
        END AS categoria,
        SUM(valor_da_operacao) OVER monthly AS total
    FROM MovimentacaoRelevanteComZeros
    WINDOW monthly AS (PARTITION BY mes, movimentacao)
    ORDER BY mes, categoria;
```

Comment: Nice answer! I got your point when you say the best practice should consider the own database query! In this way, unless the Django ORM does NOT provide this kind of complex structure query, is it possible to convert this SQL code to Django ORM?

Comment: I don't think that any ORM is expressive enough to allow such a complex query, and even if there were a way to do it in an ORM, it would probably be hard to understand such code. In any case, you are doing analytics here, not loading Python objects based on the results, so there isn't as much of an incentive to stick to the ORM. If you really want to avoid maxing raw SQL into your Python code, you could create a `VIEW` to encapsulate that query.

Comment: I'm trying to use your SQL query but Django is displaying an error: `no such function: date_trunc`. After that, I've been googling but I couldn't figure it out... I tried replacing the `date_trunc` function to `datetime(data, 'start of month')` but your fiddle code is not working. Can you help me again? My DB is SQLite.

Comment: Are you using a recent version of SQLite? With a minor change to just the datetime functions (see Rev 2 of this answer), the query works. I'm using SQLite 3.37.0.

Comment: Sorry, not working properly! I tried in my code (I'm getting different objects with the same date more than twice). Then, I went to https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=a777085e8e5ae345db8220be9d8fa126 and the info has not been showed.

Comment: That's just a quirk of dbfiddle. [The query totally does work.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=751ca668b89cbb399bf08f9dfb1a6c00)

Comment: News: Django is raising an error: "Raw query must include the primary key". Then, I edit the first SQL line to: `SELECT DISTINCT id, date(data, 'start of month') AS mes,` but the query is not being DISTINCT, some rows are being repeated. Any help again?

Comment: That sound like a Django complaint, not an SQL error. Probably a problem with your Python Django code then. Try to formulate a super simple raw SQL query in Django, then troubleshoot from there?

Comment: I've already done that and it works (e.g.: "SELECT * FROM stock_tracking_Movimentacao"). The point is: somehow Django asks for the primary key - there are some discussions here @ Stackoverflow but it didn't help me out. Is there anyway to change your SQL code from DISTINCT to GROUP BY without losing rules?

Comment: It makes no sense to require the result to include a primary key, because the results are mathematically computed, and don't correspond to any model objects. Are you sure you're using [the right technique](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/sql/#executing-custom-sql-directly)?

Comment: Tks a lot again, I was using raw sql query and now `django.db.connection` worked pretty well. But, this seems endless, I just realize there is a big mistake: if the query does NOT find "Dividendo" or "Rendimento" in any month, it should print a row anyway (e.g.: `('2022-07-01', 'Stocks', 0)`). In this way, all months will always have 2 lines: one for 'Stock' and other one for 'FII', regardless the value of `valor_da_operacao`

Comment: Yes, that's the "almost" issue that I mentioned in my answer. As I hinted, one way to solve it is to make a Common Table Expression that is a `UNION` with some fictitious 0 entries for each month, before computing the sums.

Comment: Really don't know how to do this! Do you mind if I open another question only to treat this specific issue? Maybe this could help other developers...

Comment: Added a full solution in Rev 3.

Comment: You are tireless!!! But the story never ends (remember that!): the date must be formatted as "22-Mar" (2 numbers representing `year` and 3 letters representing `month`) --> e.g.: `["19-Nov", "FII", 411.97]`. How to deal with that? Still using SQLite...

Comment: Why can't you do the date formatting in Python, as before? (See additional hint in Rev 4.)

Comment: I was trying to avoid Python code as we were maximizing the power of SQL query! How can I use Python to get date formatting without looping (`for each in sql_query`) as before? Now I'm confusing because it seems we got back to early stage...

Comment: Consider *why* I made the recommendation to use SQL. Doing the summation analysis in SQL is hugely advantageous: you can greatly reduce the number of records that have to be transferred over the connection from the database to the app. Date formatting *could* be done in SQL, but confers no such efficiency gain. In fact, it would be better architecturally to treat formatting as a presentation/internationalization issue. Keep the data as a Python `date` object, and do the `.strftime()` in your view. Similarly, you'd want to do currency/decimal formatting in your view.

Comment: I'm back again! I think I've found a mistake. If there are two 'Dividendo' with the same value (e.g.: 100) inside a month, the SQL query is not summing. See it here for `month Oct-2021`: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=c18d0996f731143249c6309ea534d623

Comment: Indeed! Fixed in Rev 5 (changed `UNION` to `UNION ALL`). I hate the way `UNION` implicitly behaves as `DISTINCT`!

Comment: Nice! I need one last help: besides `Dividendo`, the code should add `Juros Sobre Capital Próprio` inside "Stocks" categoria. In this way, if Oct-2021 finds `Dividendos = 100` and `Juros Sobre Capital Próprio = 50`, "Stocks" should have the total of 150. Fiddle example: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=30806295de974d457a22057c9dd32450

Comment: Well, I've reviewed the code that you posted, and I've also provided a complete work-alike query, which is already going beyond a review. You should be able to figure out how to maintain and extend the query — and you have already been exposed to all of the SQL concepts that you would need for your desired change.

Comment: Well, I tried this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=58a30f80e6fb6aa3bd63c28e8a7dc129. As you might know, the output was not the one I expected.